# Undo return false in an anchor

Tags: javascript

I have the following download link (client-side):

```
<a href="#" download="file.txt" onclick="return false;">download</a>
```

I want the `return false;` to be here because I want to do some stuff before downloading, and prevent the download in case of an error.

But I also want the file to download when everything goes ok, but it doesn't work. I tried `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` on mouse clicking event, but it doesn't work.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: you could `onclick='return somefunc()'` - and have somefunc conditionally return false - as long as the "do some stuff" is not asynchronous you should be golden

Comment: show your code what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

https://jsfiddle.net/y8t1eykr/

```
<a href="#" onclick="run()">download</a>
<a href="#" id="downloadFile" download="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Official_portrait_of_Barack_Obama.jpg" style="display: none;"></a>


function run() {
    var test = prompt("Write \"yes\"");
    if(test == "yes") {
        document.getElementById("downloadFile").click();
    } else {
        alert("You didn't write \"yes\"");
    }
}
```

Basically you have two elements. One that acts as your button and one with the download. If you click the button and do your thing, click the download element and it will start downloading the file.

Does this make sense? I doubt you can set `download="file.txt"` and `onclick="someFunc()` on the same file, since Javascript can't force a download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick="somefunc():` attribute as explained in the comment or you can listen to the `click` event in javascript without altering your HTML, just like this [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/bk6aou1L/1/).

on click prevent the default behavior of the anchor using javascript `.preventDefault()`:

```js
var link = document.getElementById('download'),
  file = link.getAttribute('href');

link.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert('you are trying to download ' + file);
});
```

```html
<a id="download" href="file.txt">download</a>
```